# why firebase admob is not showing ads on real device

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, admob

I added admob interstitial to my android app.

The app and interstitial are working fine on emulator, with TestID and a real ID. But on real devices it is not showing any ad, and there is no crashes or errors.

Could you please help me to find what might be the reason? Here is my code :

```
import admob, { InterstitialAd, TestIds, AdEventType  } from '@react-native-firebase/admob';
...
showAdss(){
    const idx = 'ca-app-pub-3....10';

    const interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(idx, {
      requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
      keywords: ['fashion', 'clothing']
  });

  interstitial.onAdEvent((type) => {
    if (type === AdEventType.LOADED) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
  });
```

and from manifest file :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
...
```

Comment: Are you using correct SHA-1 on firebase console?

Comment: @Eliseo I am following steps indicated in the docs , no Idea what is SHA1-1 on firebase console